# Insert with Relation into Azure Mobile Apps TableController

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I would like to insert a Parent and Child object from a Xamarin.Forms mobile app into an Azure Mobile Apps server.  I can get either the Parent and/or the Child object in via the TableController Post method, but I can never get a Child to be related to the Parent.

The result from the code snips below are that the Parent gets inserted, but the Child insertion fails because the unique key constraint is violated on the Parent (I believe it is trying to insert another Parent rather than linking).

If I just try to insert the Child without inserting the Parent then it does insert a Parent but with a 000...000 Parent.Id

This seems like a very common task, but I can find no useful tutorial or answer.  Every decent Azure Mobile Apps tutorial I could find is working from the single-table ToDo example, which works but lacks the relational example.

My server-side models are:

```
public class Parent : EntityData
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child : EntityData
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and my server TableController Post looks like (for Parent):

```
public class ParentController : TableController<Parent>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MyContext context = new MyContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Parent>(context, Request);
    }
    // POST tables/Parent
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostParent(Parent item)
    {
        Parent current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
}
```

and (for Child):

```
public class ChildController : TableController<Child>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MyContext context = new MyContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Child>(context, Request);
    }

    // POST tables/Child
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostChild(Child item)
    {
        Child current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

}
```

On the Xamarin.Forms mobile side I have models:

```
public class Parent
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and the Xamarin.Forms insert command is:

```
private async Task PostParentTask()
{
    Parent Parent = new Parent { Description = "New Parent" };
    await App.MobileService.GetTable<Parent>().InsertAsync(Parent);
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Parent", string.Format("{0} was posted with GUID {1}", Parent.Description, Parent.Id), "OK");
    Child Child = new Child { Description = "New Child", Parent = Parent};
    await App.MobileService.GetTable<Child>().InsertAsync(Child);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do direct relationships with Azure Mobile Apps.

You have to decouple the relationship, then push each table separately.

Read http://aka.ms/zumobook - particularly chapter 3 which covers the subject of relationships.

Comment: Thank you.  That book looks like a great resource!  I don't know why it never came up in probably 8hrs of searching and trying.  Google needs to direct me to what's good!

Comment: The book has been part of the answer to every SO question I've answered for perhaps the last two months - not sure why you didn't find it either!

Comment: What's the best practice for error handling here?
E.g. you push one table and the push for the second table fails.